# BIRT, repeating chart in list

Tags: eclipse, charts, birt

I have a problem using Eclipse BIRT, i'm trying to create a list with group headers including a chart relevant to the specific group header. So lets say i'm trying to create a list with all employees including their sick hours monthly in a bar chart.

**Name**

---

```
      [CHART],    Contract hours, Division, job
```

---

**Name**

---

```
      [CHART],    Contract hours, Division, job
```

---

How can i create this without creating a specific data set for every employee? This is what i am currently doing and it renders the grouping functionality of my list useless since i need to create a new dataset and list for each employee.

Regards,

Rik

Comment: What data is the chart visualizing? Is it data that is specific to the detail row you are on?

Comment: The chart would display the sick days of the year of that person. Specific to the header so in this case that persons sick days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the chart, do not bind it to the Report Data Source.  On the data tab select "Inherit Data From Container".  This will ensure the chart is bound to the data that is populating the list, not the underlying (ungrouped) data set.

Here is a smple that does what you need including a link to a live running demo.

[Dynamic Chart Creation at BIRT Exchange Dev Share](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1180-dynamic-chart-creation/)

Good Luck!